# C# Databound ComboBox Automatic Update

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox bound to a database table.
When the user inserts a new piece of data into the table, I want the combobox to be automatically updated to display this data, however I am unsure of how I would go about doing this.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar to this in a program of mine.

Whenever my datagridview is updated, I empty the combobox and refill it.

Something along the lines of (I don't have my code available right now, but this is the general idea):

```
if (!combobox.isempty())
{
    combobox.clear()
}

// Fill combobox here
```

Answer (score -1):

i think, in the moment you know you add some data to this table, you should call:

```
yourcombobox.Databind();
```

also you must define `yourcombobox.DataSource` property again, before calling `Databind()`